# In socket.io programming , all clients calls a server at same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am developing a game in node js with socket programming. New game starts again after displaying winner of old one. so problem is, i am getting acknowledgement from all clients at the same time. So one of function will execute at same time for no of acknowledgement received. And game create for no of time.Means all i wants acknowledgement one by one from all clients like all requests in queue, not at same time.

```
socket.on('winner_req',function(game_id){
    io.sockets.in("room-"+game_id).emit('winner_res',body);
});
socket.on('winner_res_ack',function(game_id){
   //here is function which i want to execute for one by one ack.
   create_game();
});
```

how can we accept call from clients one by one?

Comment: From what I understood, using nodejs asynchronous mechanism could solve your problems

Comment: Basically you need to execute functions in different threats, In Node JS you can use `asyn` functions to solve ur problem

Comment: Any example please

Comment: I think this question is about socket.io "sockets" and not net.Socket TCP/IP sockets?